# Jquery Iviewer src isnot changing while source url is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery iviewer image is binding properly for the first time.Next time if url is changed then src is not binding. src remain unchanged.
Though changing in imagepath does not affect in src, src will bind previous imagepath value.

**Code**:

```
     <script> 
function openImageBox()
{
 var imagePath="some url";
 loadImage(imagePath)
}
    var $ = jQuery;
            function loadImage(imagePath) {
                var options = {
                    src:imagePath,
                    up_on_resize: false,
                    zoom_animation: false,
                    mousewheel: false,
                    onMouseMove: function(ev, coords) { },
                    onStartDrag: function(ev, coords) { return false; }, //this image will not be dragged
                    onDrag: function(ev, coords) { }
                };
                var iv1 = $("#viewer").iviewer(options);
            }
        </script>



<div class="scanimgbackdiv invoice-popup">
      <div id="viewer" class="viewer">
</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't seem sufficient to reproduce the issue you are facing. See how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the iviewer F&Q page you need to use `$('viewer').iviewer('loadImage', url)` to update image

https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions